# Jupyter Notebook upgrade made everything disappear

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupyter Notebook and Python for a while and I had a plenty of notebooks. Today I upgraded Jupyter Notebook (`pip install --upgrade notebook`) and suddenly everything disappeared.

The console window says to copy the token in the browser, but after I paste it and run it, the webpage is still blank and nothing happens.

Operation system is Windows 7 and on my computer I have installed three different versions of python: 2.7, 3.4, 3.6 and also Pycharm and Anaconda is installed. Previously I have been using the Jupyter Notebook with the 2.7 version of Python.

I am working on an assignment project for my school. I don't even understand how can a simple upgrade install mess things up.

I am by no means an expert in Jupyter Notebook so I'd like to learn how to handle this. Please see attached the images of the blank Jupyter Notebook webpage and the console.

This is the blank webpage:

[image]

And this is the console:

[image]